# VB/C#: Placing disposible objects in global scope: Is this okay?

Tags: .net, resources, bitmap, dispose

As an optimization, I decided to put an object I frequently need - an SDL surface with a prerendered image of the entire level (called S_AreaBMP) - at global scope.
Now it doesn't have to be created and destroyed in the DrawScreen function every frame. I only need to dispose and change it when a new level or GFX sheet is loaded, which I do via this function:

```
Public Sub PrepareAreaImage()

    ''#dispose old image before it becomes unreferenced
    If AreaBMPExists
        S_AreaBMP.Dispose()
    End If
    AreaBMPExists = True

    ''#declare an appropriately sized bitmap w/ a GDI Graphics object
    Dim AreaBMP As Bitmap = New Bitmap(Area.W * TLDIM, Area.H * TLDIM)
    Dim AreaGrph As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(AreaBMP)

    ''#...(omitted: iterate through Area and draw each tile to AreaBMP)

    ''#Store to the SDL surface
    S_AreaBMP = New SdlDotNet.Graphics.Surface(AreaBMP)

    ''#Dispose
    AreaBMP.Dispose()
    AreaGrph.Dispose()
End Sub
```

(AreaBMPExists and S_AreaBMP are global scope)

**Question:** Is this fundamentally sound?

It works fine, but I can't help but feel that this sort of thing is discouraged...

Comment: Why do you think Dispose is a costly operation?
Dispose is doing some cleanup but is not necessarily costly. Can't see how a new/dispose once per frame can affect performance in any way. Specially when avoiding it messes up the code.

Comment: Oops, I was mixed up. I just looked back at the page that gave me that impression, and it's having a Finalize method that is costly, not Dispose.  I'll fix the question appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically making a static variable at a global scope.  There isn't anything technically incorrect in doing this, but it's usually a better option to wrap this using something like the [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).  This would make it easier to control access to this, and potentially easier to wrap the resource in a way to provide better thread safety, encapsulation of this logic, etc.

Comment: I know what you're saying, but I wish the GoF had never written about Singleton. Everyone and their dog thinks it's the solution to their static variable problems.

Comment: Yeah - I agree, but there are times when a Singleton makes at least some sense.  In this case, it could probably be refactored to hold the Bitmap in some form of high-level screen class, but that's beyond the scope of the question.  I do think singletons are much nicer than a single static global, though - since you can at least provide some control and thread syncrhonization.

Answer (score 0):

Thread safety would be my biggest concern. Particularly, what happens if PrepareAreaImage is called when it is already executing, or S_AreaBMP is accessed sometime during PrepareAreaImage()'s execution.